# Laravel 5 user can not be retrieved after successful authentication

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.1 and trying to implement user authentication. No routes should be accessible without login.
The built-in trait (`AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers`) does not work correctly since, after successful authentication, the redirected controller will not be able to pull out the user via `Auth::user()` or `$this->auth->user` or `$request->user()`.

I did verify that it was a successful attempt by var-dumping the user right after `$this->auth->attempt()`.

However after the redirect with `return redirect()->intended(...)`, no user can be pulled.

I am now trying to implement it by skipping the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` and writing it directly in the `AuthController` but again encountering the same problem.

This is the part in `AuthController` that does the validation:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'email'    => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required',
]);

$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

//attempt to authenticate
//if successful, redirect to the intended url or the default redirectPath
if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
{
    //when I do dd($this->auth->user()) here it shows the correct user record
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath);
}
```

It redirects to the correct URL (`HomeController`) but then the user can not be retrieved (within the `show` method or any other method):

```
dd(Auth::user()); //null
dd(Auth::check());//null
```

`HomeController` extends my `BaseController` which uses the `auth` middleware

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

I had Laravel 4 custom authentication and it was all working fine, I'm still new to the middleware authentication concept in Laravel 5.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yani you do not need to impliment that like Laravel 4, it has build in authentication you can use. I will post the resoruce fills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to use the built-in authentication in Laravel 5.1

Laravel 5.1 has built-in authentication and it works almost out of the box.

There are a few steps to do, so you will be able to use the nice default build-in Authentication template in Laravel 5.1. So you do not need to invent that wheel again like Laravel 4.0.

1- Install a fresh copy of Laravel (follow this http://laravel.com/docs/5.1) I did it by simply using this command
`composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist`

2- Create an `auth` folder in views `resources\views\auth` and copy all resources files to it from https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.0/resources/views/auth

3- Create `css` and `fonts` folder inside `public` folder and copy both folder's content from resources https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.0/public

4- Update your route file like below

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

regarding to https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.0/app/Http/routes.php

5- Create an empty database in your MySQL.

6- Update your `.env` file with database info etc.

7- Run `php artisan migrate`

8- Go to the browser and write `http://YourLaravelHostProject/auth/register`

9- (Optional) If you want to change `/home` landing page after login/registration process edit `AuthController.php` in `app\Http\Controllers\Auth`:

After this line

```
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
```

Add the code with your location

```
//forward after login
protected $redirectPath = '/YourLocation';
```

That is it. Now you have the default login/register/reset password template working. You can modify it for further use.

**php artisan migrate results**
[image]

**Browser snapshot of Login page**
[image]

It is also possible to make a simpler authentication template by following Laravel documentation.

Laravel authentication documentation http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication

Comment: Thanks. However using the built-in Laravel 5 features is causing me errors. Probably a migration problem. Currently if I try your suggestion I am getting `Cannot redeclare class Illuminate\Container\BindingResolutionException` error and I've checked 1000 times it's only being decelared once. I will try insatlling a fresh laravel project.

Comment: Yes I think that should help, you might have done some thing mean while.

Comment: I was also having another problem with the migration, related to artisan commands failing so I think it will be best to do a fresh install. I probably messed up moving from 4.2. Will try again after install.

Comment: I have updated my answer with correct step so you can get you login template to work. Let me know pls

Comment: Any process @Yani, it is late in Denmark, going to sleep now hope every thing is going as planned :) Thump up to the question is also made. gonite.

Comment: Hi Thanks for checking up with me! I just finished a fresh install and fixing some issues that are related to it. php artisan route:list was also giving me problems so I started debugging the route files (I had few routes with closure). Apparently this was mainly due to some problems in the route file + bad migration from 4.2. I don't know why it was causing the problems exactly but after I fixed everything else, your answer did help pointing me to the right direction. It is working perfectly now!! :) Thanks a bunch for your help!