# How can I re-add Laravel 5 default authentication boilerplate?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I installed Laravel, it came with some boilerplate for authentication.  For some reason, at the time, I deleted all of this.  Now I am quite deep into my project, I want to add some authentication.

Is there any way to reinstall the default code shipped with Laravel 5?

Comment: running `composer install` or `composer update` will install the original version of laravel, but be aware that all your changes will be lost if you made any to the **original** laravel files

Comment: follow this link to rebuild your authentication in Laravel 5.x http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029689/laravel-5-user-can-not-be-retrieved-after-successful-authentication/32030103#32030103

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### To re-add Laravel 5 boilerplate authentication code:

- Re-add the [Auth controllers](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth) if you deleted them, to `app/Http/Controllers/Auth`.
- Re-add the [Auth middlewares](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/app/Http/Middleware) if you deleted them.
- [Re-register](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php) any Auth middleware you deleted.
- Re-add any Authentication traits and interface implementations you removed from your [User model](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/User.php).

There are not a lot of files to add, even if you deleted all of them, so you can just copy pasta from the github repo. You'll just need to update your namespaces.

#### Laravel 5.0 had [boilerplate routes](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.0/app/Http/routes.php) that are not included in 5.1:

```php
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```