# Laravel 5.1 user login not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have a registration form which works to register and login user. 
I use `$this->middleware('auth');` in the controllers on protected routes to prompt users to login. The login form passes a `POST` request to Laravel's AuthController w/ username and password:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="XXXXXXXXXX">
    <div class="widget-content">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        <input class="btn btn-blue pull-right" type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Routes:

```
//authentication routes
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

I've tried using the authentication system's off-the-shelf `postLogin()` functionality, tried passing username, name, email to it without any luck. I tried overriding the parent method like this:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $username = $request->input('username');
    $password = $request->input('password');

    if (Auth::attempt(['name' => $username, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect('dashboard');
    } else {
        return redirect()->intended('auth/login');
    }
}
```

EDIT:

(This is old, For anyone having this issue.) The correct use of the hash function is

```
$password = Hash::make('yourPasswordString');

$result = Hash::check('yourPasswordString', $password);  //returns true
```

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: Are you trying to let them login with a username instead of email?

Comment: check steps here see if that helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029689/laravel-5-user-can-not-be-retrieved-after-successful-authentication/32030103#32030103

Comment: @Amo, no error, just redirect to auth/login. @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ, I have followed those steps. @andrewtweber I have tried both. I see the AuthenticatesUser class has this ternary: `property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'email';`  I am wondering if I'm invoking the wrong middleware?

Comment: do you have a column named name in your users table ?

Comment: @KhanShahrukh, in an attempt to debug I have changed that column name from username to name, and back and forth for the form `name="name"` / `name="username"` as well as `['name' =>` and `['usernam' =>` and `['email' =>`

Answer (score 0):

can this be the CSFR token? Since you are not using a facade to call the form you may need to add in the token call just after opening the form tag.

Here is the call:

{!! csrf_field() !!}
{!! Form::hidden('token', $token) !!}

Comment: I updated my original question to reflect the error in the way I was using the `Hash::check()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel also hashes your password if you are using inbuilt login functionality so check your model if in-case you're hashing your password.